# how to create an input text box in javascript

Tags: javascript

The table the program displays has input as the default text inside. Please I want to know how to replace it with an input text box that has an id. Thank you

```
<html>
<body>

</body>
<script>
function tableCreate(){
var body = document.body,
tbl  = document.createElement('table');
tbl.style.width  = '100px';
tbl.style.border = '2px solid black';
var n=5
for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
    var tr = tbl.insertRow()
    var td = tr.insertCell(0);
    var tf = tr.insertCell(0);  
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('input'));
    tf.appendChild(document.createTextNode('input'));
    td.style.border = '2px solid black';
    tf.style.border = '2px solid black';
    }

body.appendChild(tbl);
}
tableCreate();
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Substitute `document.createElement("input")` for `document.createTextNode("input")`; create a `form` element, include `name` attribute attribute at each `input` element created; set `id` to `"input-a" + i` and `"input-b" + i`; append `input type="submit"` to `form` element; append created `table` to `form` element

```html
<body>
  <script>
    function tableCreate() {
      var body = document.body,
        tbl = document.createElement('table');
      tbl.style.width = '100px';
      tbl.style.border = '2px solid black';
      var n = 5
      for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var tr = tbl.insertRow(); var td = tr.insertCell(0);
        var tf = tr.insertCell(0);
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.name = "input-a" + i;
        input.id = "input-a" + i;
        input.value = "";
        var clone = input.cloneNode();
        clone.name = "input-b" + i;
        clone.id = "input-b" + i;
        td.appendChild(clone);
        tf.appendChild(input);
        td.style.border = '2px solid black';
        tf.style.border = '2px solid black';
      }
      var form = document.createElement("form");
      form.appendChild(tbl);
      body.appendChild(form);
      var submit = document.createElement("input");
      submit.type = "submit";
      form.appendChild(submit)
    }
    tableCreate(); 
  </script>
</body >
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. But, I want the input elements to have id's so dt I can extract the values and also how to create a submit button that will submit all the input boxes at once. Thank you as you help

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate